# Sqoop returns "response status of 404 Not Found"

Tags: sqoop

I have installed latest Hadoop 2.5.1 and Sqoop 1.99.3 (from tarball files) on CentOS 7.
Sqoop was installed according the instructions from here: http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.3/Installation.html

I then wanted to test the Sqoop server according to this page: http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.99.3/Sqoop5MinutesDemo.html

I ran the following command:

```
show version --all
```

and got the following error message:

```
Exception: com.sun.jersey.api.client.UniformInterfaceException Message: GET http://localhost:12000/sqoop/version returned a response status of 404 Not Found
```

This is what the config and log files contain immediately after I tried to start the Sqoop server (by running **Sqoop.sh server start**):

Sqoop variables in /etc/bashrc:

```
export SQOOP_HOME="/usr/local/sqoop"
export SQOOP_CONF_DIR=$SQOOP_HOME/server/conf
```

/usr/local/sqoop/server/conf/Catalina.properties:

```
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*.jar,
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*.jar,
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*.jar,
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*.jar,
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*.jar,
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*.jar,
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/*.jar,
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*.jar,
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*.jar,
/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*.jar
```

/usr/local/sqoop/server/conf/sqoop.properties:

```
org.apache.sqoop.submission.engine.mapreduce.configuration.directory=/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/
```

/usr/local/sqoop/server/logs/localhost.2014-11-13.log:

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.apache.sqoop.server.ServerInitializer
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration
```

/usr/local/sqoop/log/sqoop.log:

```
2014-11-13 08:19:55,466 INFO  audit.AuditLoggerManager [org.apache.sqoop.audit.AuditLoggerManager.initialize(AuditLoggerManager.java:79)] Begin audit logger manager initialization
2014-11-13 08:19:55,470 WARN  audit.FileAuditLogger [org.apache.sqoop.audit.FileAuditLogger.initialize(FileAuditLogger.java:67)] appender: log4j.appender.defaultAppender
2014-11-13 08:19:55,471 INFO  audit.AuditLoggerManager [org.apache.sqoop.audit.AuditLoggerManager.initializeLoggers(AuditLoggerManager.java:126)] Audit Logger has been initialized: default
2014-11-13 08:19:55,471 INFO  audit.AuditLoggerManager [org.apache.sqoop.audit.AuditLoggerManager.initialize(AuditLoggerManager.java:85)] Audit logger manager initialized: OK
2014-11-13 08:19:55,472 INFO  repository.RepositoryManager [org.apache.sqoop.repository.RepositoryManager.initialize(RepositoryManager.java:80)] Setting system properties: {derby.stream.error.file=/usr/loc
2014-11-13 08:19:55,478 INFO  repository.JdbcRepositoryContext [org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryContext.<init>(JdbcRepositoryContext.java:154)] [repo-ctx] handler=org.apache.sqoop.repository.derb
2014-11-13 08:19:55,683 INFO  derby.DerbyRepositoryHandler [org.apache.sqoop.repository.derby.DerbyRepositoryHandler.initialize(DerbyRepositoryHandler.java:207)] DerbyRepositoryHandler initialized.
2014-11-13 08:19:55,686 INFO  repository.JdbcRepositoryProvider [org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryProvider.initializeRepositoryHandler(JdbcRepositoryProvider.java:160)] JdbcRepositoryProvider init
2014-11-13 08:19:55,686 INFO  repository.JdbcRepositoryProvider [org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryProvider.initialize(JdbcRepositoryProvider.java:67)] JdbcRepository initialized.
2014-11-13 08:19:55,686 INFO  repository.RepositoryManager [org.apache.sqoop.repository.RepositoryManager.initialize(RepositoryManager.java:118)] Creating or upgrading on disk structures if necessary
2014-11-13 08:19:56,022 DEBUG repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction [org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction.begin(JdbcRepositoryTransaction.java:73)] Tx count-begin: 1, rollback: false
2014-11-13 08:19:56,022 INFO  repository.JdbcRepository [org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepository$1.doIt(JdbcRepository.java:130)] Creating repository schema objects
2014-11-13 08:19:56,198 DEBUG derby.DerbyRepositoryHandler [org.apache.sqoop.repository.derby.DerbyRepositoryHandler.detectVersion(DerbyRepositoryHandler.java:272)] Detecting old version of repository
2014-11-13 08:19:56,354 DEBUG repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction [org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction.commit(JdbcRepositoryTransaction.java:84)] Tx count-commit: 1, rollback: false
2014-11-13 08:19:56,354 DEBUG repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction [org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction.close(JdbcRepositoryTransaction.java:103)] Tx count-close: 0, rollback: false
2014-11-13 08:19:56,354 INFO  repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction [org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction.close(JdbcRepositoryTransaction.java:111)] Attempting transaction commit
2014-11-13 08:19:56,360 DEBUG repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction [org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction.begin(JdbcRepositoryTransaction.java:73)] Tx count-begin: 1, rollback: false
2014-11-13 08:19:56,375 DEBUG derby.DerbyRepositoryHandler [org.apache.sqoop.repository.derby.DerbyRepositoryHandler.detectVersion(DerbyRepositoryHandler.java:272)] Detecting old version of repository
2014-11-13 08:19:56,375 DEBUG repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction [org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction.commit(JdbcRepositoryTransaction.java:84)] Tx count-commit: 1, rollback: false
2014-11-13 08:19:56,376 DEBUG repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction [org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction.close(JdbcRepositoryTransaction.java:103)] Tx count-close: 0, rollback: false
2014-11-13 08:19:56,376 INFO  repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction [org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction.close(JdbcRepositoryTransaction.java:111)] Attempting transaction commit
2014-11-13 08:19:56,376 INFO  repository.RepositoryManager [org.apache.sqoop.repository.RepositoryManager.initialize(RepositoryManager.java:128)] Repository initialized: OK
2014-11-13 08:19:56,377 INFO  connector.ConnectorManager [org.apache.sqoop.connector.ConnectorManager.initialize(ConnectorManager.java:174)] Connector config urls: [jar:file:/usr/local/sqoop-1.99.3-bin-had
2014-11-13 08:19:56,378 DEBUG connector.ConnectorHandler [org.apache.sqoop.connector.ConnectorHandler.<init>(ConnectorHandler.java:58)] Connector configuration: {org.apache.sqoop.connector.class=org.apache
2014-11-13 08:19:56,415 INFO  connector.ConnectorHandler [org.apache.sqoop.connector.ConnectorHandler.<init>(ConnectorHandler.java:113)] Connector [org.apache.sqoop.connector.jdbc.GenericJdbcConnector] ini
2014-11-13 08:19:56,416 DEBUG repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction [org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction.begin(JdbcRepositoryTransaction.java:73)] Tx count-begin: 1, rollback: false
2014-11-13 08:19:56,416 DEBUG repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction [org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction.begin(JdbcRepositoryTransaction.java:73)] Tx count-begin: 2, rollback: false
2014-11-13 08:19:56,416 DEBUG derby.DerbyRepositoryHandler [org.apache.sqoop.repository.derby.DerbyRepositoryHandler.findConnector(DerbyRepositoryHandler.java:441)] Looking up connector: generic-jdbc-conne
2014-11-13 08:19:56,477 DEBUG derby.DerbyRepositoryHandler [org.apache.sqoop.repository.derby.DerbyRepositoryHandler.findConnector(DerbyRepositoryHandler.java:488)] Looking up connector: generic-jdbc-conne
2014-11-13 08:19:56,477 DEBUG repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction [org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction.commit(JdbcRepositoryTransaction.java:84)] Tx count-commit: 2, rollback: false
2014-11-13 08:19:56,477 DEBUG repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction [org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction.close(JdbcRepositoryTransaction.java:103)] Tx count-close: 1, rollback: false
2014-11-13 08:19:56,478 DEBUG connector.ConnectorManager [org.apache.sqoop.connector.ConnectorManager.registerConnectors(ConnectorManager.java:227)] Registered connector: connector-generic-jdbc-connector:1
2014-11-13 08:19:56,478 DEBUG repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction [org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction.commit(JdbcRepositoryTransaction.java:84)] Tx count-commit: 1, rollback: false
2014-11-13 08:19:56,478 DEBUG repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction [org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction.close(JdbcRepositoryTransaction.java:103)] Tx count-close: 0, rollback: false
2014-11-13 08:19:56,478 INFO  repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction [org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction.close(JdbcRepositoryTransaction.java:111)] Attempting transaction commit
2014-11-13 08:19:56,478 INFO  connector.ConnectorManager [org.apache.sqoop.connector.ConnectorManager.initialize(ConnectorManager.java:200)] Connectors loaded: {generic-jdbc-connector={generic-jdbc-connect
2014-11-13 08:19:56,486 DEBUG repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction [org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction.begin(JdbcRepositoryTransaction.java:73)] Tx count-begin: 1, rollback: false
2014-11-13 08:19:56,486 DEBUG derby.DerbyRepositoryHandler [org.apache.sqoop.repository.derby.DerbyRepositoryHandler.findFramework(DerbyRepositoryHandler.java:537)] Looking up framework metadata
2014-11-13 08:19:56,503 DEBUG derby.DerbyRepositoryHandler [org.apache.sqoop.repository.derby.DerbyRepositoryHandler.findFramework(DerbyRepositoryHandler.java:583)] Looking up framework metadta found: fram
2014-11-13 08:19:56,503 DEBUG repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction [org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction.commit(JdbcRepositoryTransaction.java:84)] Tx count-commit: 1, rollback: false
2014-11-13 08:19:56,503 DEBUG repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction [org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction.close(JdbcRepositoryTransaction.java:103)] Tx count-close: 0, rollback: false
2014-11-13 08:19:56,503 INFO  repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction [org.apache.sqoop.repository.JdbcRepositoryTransaction.close(JdbcRepositoryTransaction.java:111)] Attempting transaction commit
2014-11-13 08:19:56,504 INFO  framework.FrameworkManager [org.apache.sqoop.framework.FrameworkManager.initialize(FrameworkManager.java:159)] Submission manager initialized: OK
2014-11-13 08:19:56,507 INFO  mapreduce.MapreduceSubmissionEngine [org.apache.sqoop.submission.mapreduce.MapreduceSubmissionEngine.initialize(MapreduceSubmissionEngine.java:75)] Initializing Map-reduce Sub
2014-11-13 08:19:56,512 INFO  core.SqoopServer [org.apache.sqoop.core.SqoopServer.destroy(SqoopServer.java:35)] Shutting down Sqoop server
```

According to the last line in the log file, the Sqoop server shutdown itself and doesn't start. I googled every possible combination of error messages above and didn't find anything that could have helped. How can I troubleshoot this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This is common when the hadoop libs can't be found. There are two things you can do:

1. Install Sqoop through apache Big Top or through one of the Hadoop distributors (ie [Cloudera](http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/downloads.html))
2. Edit the tomcat configuration to include these jars (as you've tried above). The log file is giving you specifics in terms of which classes are missing. You can [search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3497664/how-to-find-the-jar-file-containing-a-class-definition) for your missing jars via the command line.

I highly recommend the first option.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! I double checked the catalana.properties file, and made sure the common.loader section is a single line. If this section consists of the multiple lines, the TomCat will not load Sqoop webapp. Line breaks are not accepted.